# Использование правила в BeatifulfulSoup полученного из configparser

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup

У меня возникает проблема при передачи параметра ,полученного из конфиг. файла, т.к. он приходит ,как строка.

```
@property
def get_rule(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(path)
    title_rule = config.get(self.site_name, "title")
    return title_rule


print(self.get_rule)
'h1', {'class': 'title'}


[pravda.ru]
title = 'h1', {'class': 'title'}
```

Пытаюсь передать в BeatifulfulSoup:

```
print(self.get_page.find(self.get_rule))
None
```

Но если я передаю:

```
print(self.get_page.find('h1', {'class': 'title'}))
<h1 class="title">text</h1>
```

или

```
rule = 'h1', {'class': 'title'}
print(self.get_page.find(rule))
<h1 class="title">text</h1>
```

То все работает правильно!

Проблема возникает только если передавать список или использовать значение полученное из конфига:

```
rule = "'h1', {'class': 'title'}"
print(self.get_page.find(rule))
None
```

Подскажите ,как правильно получить значение из конфига , чтобы beautifullsoup его нормально принял?

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

text = """<html>
<body>
<h1 itemprop="headline">Title</h1>
<h1 class="title">Another title</h1>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
print(soup.select("h1[itemprop='headline']"))
```

Если сделать вот так, то все работает. Т.е. select_one("h1[itemprop='headline']") , заменяет find('h1', {'itemprop': 'headline'}).